# Unexpected performance gain from adding padding in class

Tags: c++, performance

```
class B {
  public:
    // member functions
  private:
    *padding location 1*
    alignas(64) atomic<long> x;
    alignas(64) atomic<long> y;
    *padding location 2*
};

class A {
  public:
     // member functions
  private:
     // other data members ...
     ...
     **external location 1**
     B b1;
     **external location 2**
     B b2;
     **external location 3**
     B b3;
     // more data members ...
};
```

In the code above, if I add some padding at **location 1**, e.g `char padding[64]`,(64 being the cache line size on my machine) then I saw a noticeable speedup (around tens of micro-seconds, which is considerable for my lowish-latency application). However, no such effects were observed if I moved the padding to **location 2** (end of `class B`). Similarly, if I try to add the padding externally in `class A` at **external locations 1, 2, and 3**, there was no difference either. I suspect it had something to do with the cache line alignments for `x` and `y`, but could not come up any theory to explain why it only had an effect if the padding was added before `B::x`. I'd think the `alignas` specifier already ensured `x` and `y` to be on separate cache lines, so adding the padding before `x` should not affect it much at all?

Maybe it has nothing to do with the cache line placements? Any alternative theory is great. I am also looking for suggestions about what experiment/tools I should run/use to understand what is going on here.

Comment: You could interrogate where the members of you classes wind up with [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)

Comment: What is the target processor used to run the program? Is it an Intel processor? If yes, can you check with 128 instead of 64 for the alignement?

Comment: @JérômeRichard. Yes I am using an Intel processor. I've already tried with 128 alignments for `x` and `y`, as well as adding another padding of 64 bytes between them. The behaviours are the same as what I've described